# nHibernate - Adding aggregate functions in .select

Tags: nhibernate, aggregate-functions, queryover

I am trying to implement a business formula in QueryOver.

`POorder.Estimate` is a calculated field and I need to get

```
ToDateOrderAmount = POrder.Estimate - Sum(PODist.Field1) - Sum(PODisTaxRebate.Field1 + PODisTaxRebate.Field2)
```

So I need to write a query. What I have now is:

```
    var reportModels =
        Session.QueryOver<Domain.Model.Purchasing.Vendor>(() => v)
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => v.Invoices, () => invoice)
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => invoice.PurchaseOrder, () => poOrder)
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => poOrder.PurchaseOrderDistributions, () => poDistribution)
            .Left.JoinQueryOver(() => poDistribution.TaxRebate, () => poTaxRebate)
            .SelectList(
                list =>
                list.Select(() => v.Number).WithAlias(() => varptModel.VendorNumber)
                    .Select(() => v.TypeCode.Code).WithAlias(() => varptModel.VendorType)
                    .Select(() => v.Name).WithAlias(() => varptModel.VendorName)
                    .Select(() => v.PurchasingContactPhoneNumber + "-Ext." + v.PurchasingContactPhoneNumberExt).WithAlias(() => varptModel.Phone)
                    .Select(() => v.Address).WithAlias(() => varptModel.Address)
                    .Select(() => invFiscalYear.Year).WithAlias(() => varptModel.Year)
                    .Select(() => invoice.TotalAmount).WithAlias(() => varptModel.InvoiceToDate)
                    .Select(() => invoice.AmountPaidToDate).WithAlias(() => varptModel.PaymentToDate)
                    .Select(() => poOrder.Estimate).WithAlias(() => varptModel.OrdersToDate)
        .Select(() => poOrder.Estimate - Sum(poDistribution.Field1) - Sum(poTaxRebate.Discount1 + poTaxRebate.Discount2) )
                    ).List();
```

But this is not right. What should I change it to?

Comment: What SQL are you trying to generate?

Comment: First of all glad to see you as I started learning nHibernate from your blog or site a month ago. Here I am trying to implement a business formula in to QueryOver. POorder.Estimate is a calculated field where need to get ToDateOrderAmount = POrder.Estimate - Sum(PODist.Field1) - Sum(PODisTaxRebate.Field1 + PODisTaxRebate.Field2). If you want then I can send whole query.

Comment: Moved information from comment into the body. However the post still needs to more clearly explain what the problem is, what happens when the provided code is used etc.

Comment: Thanks KateGregory for improving my question.

Comment: What error are you getting now? Also, you have to be grouping by a property to use `Sum`

Comment: I am not able to complete the query as dont know the correct syntax of this requirement. Looking for the correct way to write this. Error would be the next stage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried many things and found this working

```
.Select(Projections.SqlFunction(new VarArgsSQLFunction("", "+", ""),
                                NHibernateUtil.Double,
                                Projections.SqlFunction(new VarArgsSQLFunction("", "+", ""),
                                NHibernateUtil.Double,
                                Projections.Sum(Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", NHibernateUtil.Double, Projections.Property(() => invoiceLineItem.Expense), Projections.Constant(0))),
                                Projections.Sum(Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", NHibernateUtil.Double, Projections.Property(() => invitemTaxRebate.Rebate1Expense), Projections.Constant(0)))),
                                Projections.Sum(Projections.SqlFunction("coalesce", NHibernateUtil.Double, Projections.Property(() => invitemTaxRebate.Rebate2Expense), Projections.Constant(0)))))
                                .WithAlias(() => varptModel.ToDateInvoices)
```

which gave me this in SQL

```
sum(coalesce(invoicelin8_.Expense, 0 )) + sum(coalesce(invitemtax9_.Rebate1Expense, 0 )) + sum(coalesce(invitemtax9_.Rebate2Expense, 0 ))
```

I added Coalesce as when we add or subtract values with null value, all values becomes null in result. Just a hint for new ones.